# Google Fit PHP - Multiuser API

Tags: php, google-fit

I need to integrate Google Fit data on a project in PHP.
The idea is that every user, if he wants, can authorize the download of his Google Fit data.

Now, I was wondering if there are bees to handle this situation. Also if they are free.
Have you ever come across something like this? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "bees"?  The only way you can access a user's data via the REST API is to have an oauth token granted by that user, and to make separate requests for individual users.

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit's REST API only supports requests from a single user.

The only way you can access multiple users' data is for each of those users to have given you an OAuth token which grants access to their data; you then need to make separate requests for each user's data using that user's OAuth token.